# css transform causes flicker on modal in chrome

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I have created a modal using semantic-ui. when I click on a button the modal opens.
I have modified css properties for the modal as follow:

```
#modal {
  width: 400px !important;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%) !important;  
  right: 50% !important;
  left: auto !important;
  top: 50% !important;
  margin: auto !important;
  position: fixed;
}
```

When I click on the button on chrome or edge browser, the modal opens and after couple of seconds it jumps to a new position. Firefox does not show this problem.
Also if I remove transform: translate(50%, -50%) !important;   line, I don't see the problem

You can see the problem in this codepen:
http://codepen.io/masoudhosseini/pen/rjjpbd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem, I need to disable animation on modal for it to display correctly in chrome and edge:

```
$("#btn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#modal").modal({
        blurring: true,
        duration: 0
    }).modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

used this css and js

```
`$("#btn").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$("#modal").modal({
    blurring: true,

}).modal('show');`
```

`var modaleheight = $("#modal").height();
      $("#modal").css('margin-top', -(modaleheight/2) );
});`

`#modal {width: 400px !important; right: 0 !important; left: 0 !important; top: 50% !important; margin: auto; position: fixed;}`

Comment: it does not center the modal vertically